# How to call method to avoid cross threaded call

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, methods, invoke

How to call  method `sendResponse` to cross threaded call?

```
 void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.FullPath);            
            sendResponse(e.FullPath); //this method must causes cross threaded call
        }
```

I was trying :

```
  Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {                

            });
```

or  `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke`

But there is no `Current` .

How to deal with that?

I tried also:

```
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {...}
```

But there is no InvokeRequired.

**EDIT** I get unsupported exception when I create any object like `Bitmap` in `sendResponse` method. This method is called after firing event. So I thought it is crossthreading.

```
       void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.FullPath);

            sendResponse(e.FullPath);
        }

 private void sendResponse(string path) {
            try {


                    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@path, UriKind.Relative));
                    byte[] data;
                    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmi));
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                        encoder.Save(ms);
                        data = ms.ToArray();
                    }
                clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e); }
        }
```

**EDIT2** Client is widnows phone.. this(client) stopped worked after using code from the Nikita's answer(server stopped trhowing exceptions)

```
  try {
                            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(e.Buffer, e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);


                                BitmapImage im = new BitmapImage();
                                im.SetSource(stream);

                                MainPage.page.imagePanel.Source = im;
                             });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in send response?  Is the file being passed in already a JPEG?  BitmapImage is a WPF UI control, you shouldn't be using one in non UI code.  There are probably better ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the target platform? WPF? Windows Phone?

Comment: @Noseratio Yes, it is Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform a call on UI thread, then you should save the reference to dispatcher by calling

```
 _dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
```

**on UI thread**. Then you can access it on non-UI thread and use `_dispatcher.BeginInvoke` or `_dispatcher.Invoke` in your `watcher_Created` method.

If you simply want to make your code threadsafe - you can wrap the call in the `lock` statement:

```
private readonly object _sendLock = new object();

void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.FullPath);            
     lock(_sendLock) 
     {
         sendResponse(e.FullPath);
     }
}
```

**Edit:** you do not need to use wpf components for opening a bitmap and you should not. Instead, for example, you can do the following:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (Image img = Image.FromStream(File.OpenRead(@path)))
{
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    var data = ms.ToArray();
    clientStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: My Application has no `Current` anywhere. Please look at my edit  of OP pleeeeaaaase.

Comment: This bitmap has to be converted to bytes. Where did I use WPF controls to open a bitmap? That could be helpfull. I do not want to save

Comment: @Yoda, replace a file stream with memory stream then, doesnt make much difference

Comment: I made a mistake in explaining. I need to open a jpg file then convert it to byte[] buffer then send it over TCP. It works but only once ;p i get these exceptions./  Could you show the alternative. I am not lying..(lie) I work straight for 48 hours no sleep. I am little slow now.

Comment: I open the file then put it in byty[] array. Then send the array.

Comment: @Yoda you open a bitmap file, conver it to jpg, and then send it. If that is what you need, look at example in my answer.

Comment: Now the exceptions on the sender side dissapeared but now the images on receiver side are not displayed(WindowsPhone) Before change the first sent was displayed, rest was not. EDIT2

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much of experience with WP8, but I think you should be able to use synchronization context, which is a universal concept. When your ViewModel or a UI element is created on the UI thread, remember the thread's current synchronization context:

```
SynchronizationContext _uiSyncContext;

// ...
_uiSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

Later from the background thread, use [`SynchronizationContext.Post`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (asynchronous callback) or [`SynchronizationContext.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (synchronous callback) to execute code on the UI thread:

```
_uiSyncContext.Post((_) => { this.textBox.Text = "Hello"; }, null);
```